# pandas conditional replacement of cell values with mean / median over rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and have 2 (big) unstacked pandas dataframes with dates as rows and columns as ids. The first dataframe contains certain values while the second contains the (row) rank of each value. I would like to replace rank values with their row median when a condition on the value itself is met.

Here is the problem (suppose that dfval contains float numbers):

```
dfrank = (dfval).rank(axis=1,method='first',ascending=False)
```

and this seems ok. Then I would like to do something like

```
dfrank[ dfval < 0.546 ] = dfrank.median(axis=1)
```

which fails. I could not find an appropriate solution, I think I am messing up with indexes?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you a sample of the dataframe

Comment: dfval could be like follows (the preview of the real one is full of nan that's why I am not posting it)
   dfval = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2000-01-01','2000-01-02','2000-01-03']*3,'id':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']})
dfval['val'] = np.random.normal(size=len(dfval))
dfval = dfval.set_index(['date','id'])['val'].unstack()

Comment: sorry I made a mess, the answer below looks very fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
np.random.seed(100)
dfval = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (dfval)
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.004719
1  0.121569  0.670749  0.825853  0.136707  0.575093
2  0.891322  0.209202  0.185328  0.108377  0.219697
3  0.978624  0.811683  0.171941  0.816225  0.274074
4  0.431704  0.940030  0.817649  0.336112  0.175410

dfrank = (dfval).rank(axis=1,method='first',ascending=False)
print (dfrank)
     A    B    C    D    E
0  2.0  4.0  3.0  1.0  5.0
1  5.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  3.0
2  1.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  2.0
3  1.0  3.0  5.0  2.0  4.0
4  3.0  1.0  2.0  4.0  5.0

print (dfrank.median(axis=1))
0    3.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
dtype: float64

dfrank = dfrank.mask(dfval < 0.546 , dfrank.median(axis=1), axis=0)
print (dfrank)
     A    B    C    D    E
0  3.0  3.0  3.0  1.0  3.0
1  3.0  2.0  1.0  3.0  3.0
2  1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
3  1.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0
4  3.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0
```

Comment: Really nice answer sir. I could not think of the data. I need more experience for that.